# How to do an outer join when eager loading with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, outer-join

I could find an answer to this, but please point me to anything I might have overlooked: I wonder how to do an outer (full) join when eager loading with sequelize in node.js?

Working now with following:

```
Messages.findAll({ include: [{model: User, required: true}]})
```

This gives me an inner join if I'm not wrong. Messages and Use have a 1 to many relationship & I am attempting to pass the username (as stored in User) to the client, which expects the property on the results array to be 'username'. But here I am only getting a User object with the username property attached.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the model definitions?  Also, perhaps post the generated SQL by including `logging: console.log` in the query options?   According to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance) setting `required: true` will always give you a INNER JOIN, so maybe say `required: false`.